# How to call function inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jstree

```js
<script type="text/javascript>
function submitMe() {
    var checked_ids = [];
    $('#your-tree-id').jstree('get_checked',null,true).each(function(){
        checked_ids.push(this.id);
    });
    //setting to hidden field
    document.getElementById('jsfields').value = checked_ids.join(',');
}
</script>
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="jsfields" id="jsfields" value="">
```

I'm searching the way to get checked Ids of Jstree in form submit. So this is what I get. However, how I can call this function in my program?

Comment: when do you want to call the function?

Comment: do you want to call submitMe function from the submit button/other part of javascript? Please mention in the question.

Comment: Just add your submitMe function to your form onsubmit event <form onsubmit="submitMe()"> </form>

Comment: @dex ya, i want to call it from the submit button

Comment: @guradio i want to call the function when i click the submit button

Comment: @user3273700 i try that method but it can't get the value

Answer (score 0):

Use a click/submit event

```
$(form).submit(submitMe);
```

or

```
$('[type="submit"]').click(submitMe);
```

Don't forget to prevent the default event and then trigger it after the code:

```
function submitMe(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var checked_ids = [];
    $('#your-tree-id').jstree('get_checked',null,true).each(function(){
        checked_ids.push(this.id);
    });
    //setting to hidden field
    document.getElementById('jsfields').value = checked_ids.join(',');
   window.location = $(this).closest('form').submit();
}
```